# How to select folder from treeview and display file name to listbox C#?

Tags: c#

I has a problem with treeview that's I select 1 folder from treeview and my listbox  will display folder's file name

I can only display the file of the first folder

I want to display the file name of each folder when selected

How can I do that ?

This is my code:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Lấy các Disk trong Explorer
        GetDisk();

     }

    //Get Disk
    public void GetDisk() 
    {
        string[] disk = Directory.GetLogicalDrives();
        for (int i = 0; i < disk.Length; i++)
        {
            tvFolder.Nodes.Add(disk[i]);
            GetFol(disk[i], i);

        }
    }

    //Get Folder 
    public void GetFol(string name, int lv)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] fd = Directory.GetDirectories(name);
            for (int i = 0; i < fd.Length; i++ )
            {
                tvFolder.Nodes[lv].Nodes.Add(fd[i]);
                //Sub Dir
                if (Directory.Exists(fd[i]))
                {
                    tvFolder.Nodes[lv].Nodes.Add("Temp");
                }
            }
            GetFile(name);
        }
        catch //(Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    //Get File Function
    public void GetFile(string nameFol)
    {
        string[] strFile = Directory.GetFiles(nameFol);

        for (int i = 0; i < strFile.Length; i++)
        {
            //Get File Image
            string strExtension = strFile[i].Substring(strFile[i].LastIndexOf('.') + 1).ToLower();
            if (strExtension == "jpg" || strExtension == "jpeg" || strExtension == "png" || strExtension == "gif")
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(strFile[i]);
                lsbImages.Items.Add(strFile[i]);
            }
        }

    }
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you not handling treeview node selection:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetDisk();
    tvFolder.AfterSelect += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventHandler(tvFolder_AfterSelect);
}

//...

private void tvFolder_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    GetFile(e.Node.Text);
}
```

**Get more:**

- [GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) vs [EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [GetDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories(v=vs.110).aspx) vs [EnumerateDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratedirectories(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: it's working but it's duplicate file when I select other folder and
I want to delete line old file when I change select ... How can I to do it ?

Comment: clear listbox items:    public void GetFile(string nameFol)
    { ... lsbImages.items.clear();  ...